# Solr connectivity issue in Azure

Tags: solr, upgrade

I have setup Sitecore 10.3 instance in Azure and Solr hosted in Azure VM machine. Solr is not connecting and we are getting the below exception.

```
Job started: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Examining schedules (count:0)
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #4 07:27:34 WARN  **IsOnline: Test connection has failed with an exception. Type: 'SolrConnectionException', Message: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'intdev-solr.atcc.org''**
ManagedPoolThread #4 07:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.HtmlCacheClearAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.HtmlCacheClearAgent
ManagedPoolThread #5 07:27:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #5 07:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Examining schedules (count:5)
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Not due: Reset Failed Automated Messages
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Not due: Missing
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Not due: Older
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Not due: Recent
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Not due: Today
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: 5)
4636 07:27:36 WARN  [Index=sitecore_testing_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
8432 07:27:36 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
3552 07:27:36 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
3612 07:27:36 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
3776 07:27:42 WARN  [Index=sitecore_testing_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
6768 07:27:42 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
8756 07:27:42 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
4636 07:27:42 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
ManagedPoolThread #6 07:27:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #6 07:27:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
8356 07:27:48 WARN  [Index=sitecore_testing_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
4656 07:27:48 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
6768 07:27:48 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
8432 07:27:48 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:54 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 07:27:54 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
4656 07:27:54 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
8384 07:27:54 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_master_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
4636 07:27:54 WARN  [Index=sitecore_testing_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
7844 07:27:54 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.
```

We have checked in-bound and out-bound rules and allowed my Solr port.

Could anyone please help me here if any one has faced similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: This is nothing to do with ports, its to do with DNS not setup correcty for the domain, Try ping domain and see if works

Comment: Try ping domain and see if works--> the command would be ping followed by solr url correct ?

Comment: from CMD window type ping intdev-solr.atcc.org

Comment: PS C:\home\site\wwwroot> ping intdev-solr.atcc.org

ping intdev-solr.atcc.org

Ping request could not find host intdev-solr.atcc.org. Please check the name and try again. Getting above exception

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, I can see that the reason for the initial exception is that your DNS has not been correctly configured for the sub domain `intdev-solr.atcc.org`

Therefore you need to either correctly register the `intdev-sol` sub domain (with who ever controls the main domain i.e. `atcc.org`).

Or you need to add a local DNS rule on the machines trying to reach it. If the machine is a windows machine, then you should be able to do this as follows:

1. find the IP address of the SOLR VM (this can be external or internal if all VMS in same azure subscription)
2. open notepad as administrator
3. open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
4. add entry at bottom of file: `<your-solr-ip-address> intdev-solr.atcc.org`

**Update**

I thought of one further option you might consider. If you are using an Azure VM to host your SOLR instance, then you could configure a DNS name for the machine. To do this:

1. Go to VM overview screen
2. Look for 'DNS Name'
3. Click 'Not configured' link
4. Add 'DNS name label'
   [image: DNS Label]

Your domain will be similar to: `intdev-solr.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` (depending on your data center). You should then be able to generate a self signed certificate in Azure to use for testing purposes.

See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server

Comment: in azure web app level how to add host name

Comment: I dont think its possible to add local DNS rules to azure web app. In this situation, you will need to configure DNS on the main domain.